# Angularjs routing with data

Tags: jquery, angularjs

When i click on view Button from department list Data not showing on view template. i am not using any service. 
please help me someone.........

my source code is given below ......

My Angularjs Controller:

```
    .when('/Edit/:Id', {
        templateUrl: baseSiteUrlPath + 'Templates/Hrm_dept/Edit.html',
        controller: 'DeptCtrl'
    })
```

DeptApp.controller('DeptCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, $route) {

```
$scope.Dept = {};
$scope.Dept1 = {};
$scope.DeptList = [];
$scope.DeptList1 = [];
$scope.ishide = true;   

$scope.DeptView = function (Dept) {
    console.log(Dept);
    **$scope.Dept1 = angular.copy(Dept);**
    var id = 1;
    **var earl = '/Edit/' + id;**
    $location.path(earl);
    $scope.$apply();
};

});
```

Here is My List Template:
**ng-click="DeptView(Dept)"**

Here is My View Template:
Dept Name: ng-model="Dept1.DEPT_NAME"

Comment: instead of jQuery.ajax try $http

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? `$scope.$apply()` could probably be throwing an error

Comment: Yes . Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress but if i comment // $scope.$apply() dont show error but not show any data to view template.

Comment: how to pass object with angularjs routing

    .when('/Edit/:Id', {
        templateUrl: baseSiteUrlPath + 'Templates/Hrm_dept/Edit.html',
        controller: 'DeptCtrl'
    })

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (don't forget to declare `$http` in your controller)

```
$http.get('/HRM_DEPT/GetAllDepartment').
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.DeptList = data;
     // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
      });
```

Comment: List is showing but when i click on view buttion from list of dept and fire this function then Dept value not showing to view template ..
 $scope.DeptView = function (Dept) {
    console.log(Dept);
    $scope.Dept1 = angular.copy(Dept);
    var id = 1;
    var earl = '/Edit/' + id;
    $location.path(earl);
    $scope.$apply();
};